# Audio In to BT out on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I want to get audio in (from TV or other audio source) into iPhone and use iPhones capabilities to send this audio over Bluetooth (BT) to a external BT receiver. Any possibilities to get audio in via the headphone connector or lightning dock and then output this audio via BT?